# Can Ember-Data scale well for non CRUD setup of a complicated webapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ember.js, crud, ember-data

I am using EmberJS and now planning to get the ember-data integrated in for models.
We are using Rails/MongoDB as backend. I went through examples and updated documentation at the Ember website but there is one thing common across all discussions/examples that we must have the data flowing in CRUD and effectively rails exposes everything as resource in the router.rb

In my practical experience the REST APIs for a touch complex backend may not remain CRUD for every model in the data base. There will be lots of REST APIs which deliver JSON on various query strings. How exactly a Data Store can be applied to such cases. Is there any live example/reference to this.

In a broad sense extracting from Tom Dale's talk on Ember Data will help in supporting offline data store, but how this whole concept scales for the sites which bank on database queries which are more complex then find_by_id (Rails equivalent) of Ember DS find.

Any references of sample sources/projections of DataStore for complex services might be help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'd want to write your own adapter rather than using the RESTAdapter if things become non-standard. By doing this you can define how your adapter will query and load records from the server. The RESTAdapter is intended for basic queries, but can be extended for small modifications. This link shows a pretty decent custom adapter.

https://github.com/karmi/ember-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/ember-data/lib/adapters/elasticsearch_adapter.js

You may want to reference this link as the above app should still work, but things are still being worked on and this shows any breaking changes to the API.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md

Comment: And same is the case with the serializer ?

Comment: Yes. With the ability to write custom adapters and serializers, or just extending the existing ones and modifying as needed there hasn't been a single thing I couldn't overcome with Ember Data.